# Cant iterate through multiple pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

So I was attempting to iterate through two series that I obtained from a Pandas DF, and I found that I could not iterate through them to return numbers less than 280.000. I also realized that I could not iterate over lists either. Is there any way I can iterate over multiple lists, series, etc? thanks.
Example below:

```
two_series = df['GNP'], df['Population']

def numb():
            for i in two_series:
                if i < 280.000:
                    print(i)
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input and desired output.

Comment: If you're attempting to get rows where GNP or Population is less than a certain value, you can use: `df[(df[['GNP', 'Population]] < 280000).any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, two_series is just a tuple with two elements, each of which is a Series. So when you loop through all the elements of two_series, i is the whole series, and you only loop twice. It doesn't make sense to ask if a Series is less than 280, so it throws an error.

You could just concatenate the series, like this:

```
two_series = df['GNP'].append(df['Population'])
```

Or you could just add a second nested loop to go through each of the items in each series:

```
for i in two_series:
    for entry in i:
        if entry < 280.000:
            print(entry)
```